# get data from post request in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I got problem to get data from post request. I got error `415`. When I check it. It just post like this `Today News`. is it supposed to post like this.

```
{

    "mediasource": "Today News"
}
```

Where should I change to make it work and How to get data list after post

**HTML**

```
<div class="card-body" (click)="TNews(mediasource='Today News')">
<img class="img-news" src="../../../assets/images/newsicon/news.png">
<h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"></h6>
<p class="card-text">Today News</p>
 </div>
```

Component

```
TNews(mediasource){
    console.log(mediasource)
    this.HomeNewsService.getTopNews(mediasource).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
    });

    }
```

**Service**

```
export interface NewsRequest {
  mediaSource: string;
  }

getTopNews(mediaSource:NewsRequest) {
    console.log(mediaSource)
    return this.http.post(environment.apiBaseUrl+'/home/topnews', mediaSource).pipe(
      map((res: Response) =>{
        if(res['code'] !== 0){
          throw new Error(res['message']);
        }
      })
    )
  }
```

Comment: Check your API for correct CORS headers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: Cross Origin Request is something you have to add in backend code. You have to enable the CORS in your backend code or you need to configure CORS in your server side (Ex : IIS)

Comment: No it problem just because I post not follow the json rule.. It should post like this `{

    "mediasource": "Today News"
}`

Comment: But it post only `Today News`

Comment: @javiens then i feel it should be bad request (400).

Comment: @AkhilNaidu no, I got 415 error

Comment: Still the issue exists? or it is resolved?

Comment: @AkhilNaidu Still exists..

Comment: If the issue is 415 unsupported media type try to add `Content-Type: application/json` and `Accept: application/json` in http headers section at client side, or if the issue is with CORS then you have to enbale CORS at your server side.

Comment: @AkhilNaidu Okey I will try... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for that, you need to use a proxy script and name it **proxy.conf.json** inside your program/angular app.create it in the root of the project near package.json and other neighboring files.

```
     {
      "/api/**": {
        "target": "http://192.168.1.4:8080",
        "secure": false,
        "loglevel": "debug",
        "changeOrigin": true
      }
    }
```

point to your backend server. Then update the package.json as below

```
       "start": "ng serve --open --port 4400   --proxy-config proxy.conf.json ",
```

and start your angular app by

```
npm start
```

for the production, you need to configure your proxy with the whatever server you choose, for example, if you are using nginx, [check this nginnx docs](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) and this is called reverse proxy.
for more on angular proxy script [check this article](https://medium.com/better-programming/setup-a-proxy-for-api-calls-for-your-angular-cli-app-6566c02a8c4d)
hope this helps.